# where to put hashkey into facebook developers page?

Tags: android, facebook

I am currently developing an application for android with using facebook API. But even though I create an app on facebook and insert it's app_id into my code, I get this message when I try to log in to facebook:

"This app has no android key hashes configured, configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/1232412xxxxxxxx"

I followed this guide :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

and get hash key, but I couldn't find what to do with this hash key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,

- I coppied my hashkey.
- Navigated to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
- Selected my app
- Selected "Native Android App" under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"

Here was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

App homepage -> Settings -> Add Platform -> Android -> Keyhashes